# reproducible npm install without shrinkwrap (ignore packages released after a given date)

Tags: npm, installation, date-range, transitive-dependency

Recently I've run into an issue where a new version of some transitive dependency of `babel-eslint` fails to parse Flow parameterized types.  Downgrading `babel-eslint` didn't work because the newer versions of the transitive deps are semver-compatible with the older version of `babel-eslint`.

Since a fresh `npm install` worked fine several months ago, if there was a time machine-like feature whereby it would install exactly the same packages as it would have on a specific date several months ago, I should be able to get a working project setup again.

Is there a way to make `npm` <strike>party</strike>`install` like it's 2015?

Answer (score 0):

You can (and probably should) avoid getting into this fix by using `npm shrinkwrap --dev` to lock down versions of all dependencies.

However, if you've gotten stuck with a broken project, and you're having trouble figuring out what transitive deps to roll back to earlier versions, you can use [this fork](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/12995) of npm I created that allows you to `npm install --ignore-versions-after=2016-05-03` (or whatever date you remember it working on) to get back working deps, and then `npm shrinkwrap --dev`.